# use div inside give table

Tags: php, html

Can I use a div inside the table given here. I can't use the div tag inside foreach.

here is my code

```
<table border="1" class="table table-stripped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td></td>
            <?php foreach($tests as $test){?>
                <td><?php echo $test->name;?></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($tests[0]->test_attributes as $test_attribute){?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <?php echo $test![enter image description here][1]_attribute->attribute_name;?>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: which `div` and how do you want this?

Comment: `i cant use div tag inside foreach.` Here're two foreach loops. In which you can't use div and why?

Comment: The question is 'why not?'.

Answer (score 1):

```
<table border="1" class="table table-stripped table-bordered">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <?php foreach($tests as $test){?>
                <td><div><?php echo $test->name;?></div></td>
            <?php } ?>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <?php foreach($tests[0]->test_attributes as $test_attribute){?>
        <tr>
            <td>
                <div><?php echo test_attribute->attribute_name;?></div>
            </td>
        </tr>
        <?php } ?>
    </tbody>
</table>
```

[image]

Comment: see the picture.can i use div inside that space?is that possible?i cant use div tag inside foreach loop.